# Is there any problem with my IDE or code?

Tags: c++, codeblocks, bgi

I want to learn the basics of graphic.h library in cpp, but after solving a few errors with the IDE and running some codes from tutorials found on youtube I encountered another problem. After compiling and running the code, the console opens, but a new interface does not. I have used two functions for this, openwindow() and initgraph(), both with the same result. I do not know if I do something wrong. Does someone know what can I do to solve this?

IDE: CodeBlocks

Update:
Some of you said that this library is a bit too old and out of support rn. Do you have any recommendations for other graphic libraries in cpp?

Code:

```
#include <graphics.h>
int main(void)
{
    int gd=DETECT,gm;
    initgraph(&gd,&gm,"");
    line(100, 200, 100, 200);
    getch();
    closegraph();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect it to happen? Are there any error logs?

Comment: Which graphics library are you using?  Did you configure the search paths in CodeBlocks for the graphics library?

Comment: I expect it to open a new interface and draw a line, i saw it in a tutorial as a method of testing if I have any error if I run code using that library.  There is one warning while running the code..
Update: now is not showing any warning while compiling and running.
The graphics library is WinBGIm. Yes, I had, it is seeing the library and the code is running fine, but no interface is opened as it was in the tutorial while running that code.

Comment: The problem is with using a library of which the useful lifetime has ended 25 years ago.

Comment: Yeah, I came across this information, i had to set up my compiler to run on 32 bit instead of 64bit, any recommendations for a graphic library in c++?

Comment: SDL2 should be good enough for basic 2D. When you'll need more, you can use SDL2+OpenGL.

Comment: I will try it, thank you